# yuicompressor plugin execution not covered in m2e

Tags: maven, m2eclipse, yui-compressor

After a long search for a JavaScript compressor I could use in Maven, I finally found one:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>yuicompressor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compress</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <jswarn>false</jswarn>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Now in the latest version of m2e in Eclipse, I get the following error:

> Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: net.alchim31.maven:yuicompressor-maven-plugin:1.1:compress (execution: default, phase: process-resources)

Lovely. I don't get it---it's just a plugin. Why can't m2e simply call any old plugin I have? What's wrong with this one? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See http://wiki.eclipse.org/M2E_plugin_execution_not_covered

> To solve some long-standing issues,
>   m2e 1.0 requires explicit instructions
>   what to do with all Maven plugins
>   bound to "interesting" phases (see [M2E
>   interesting lifecycle phases](http://wiki.eclipse.org/M2E_interesting_lifecycle_phases)) of
>   project build lifecycle. We call these
>   instructions "project build lifecycle
>   mapping" or simply "lifecycle mapping"
>   because they define how m2e maps
>   information from project pom.xml file
>   to Eclipse workspace project
>   configuration and behaviour during
>   Eclipse workspace build.
>
> Project build lifecycle mapping
>   configuration can be specified in
>   project pom.xml, contributed by
>   Eclipse plugins and there is also
>   default configuration for some
>   commonly used Maven plugins shipped
>   with m2e. We call these "lifecycle
>   mapping metadata sources". m2e will
>   create error marker like below for all
>   plugin executions that do not have
>   lifecycle mapping in any of the
>   mapping metadata sources.
>
> ```
> Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration:
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.3:run
>    (execution: generate-sources-input, phase: generate-sources)
> ```
>
> m2e matches plugin
>   executions to actions using
>   combination of plugin groupId,
>   artifactId, version range and goal.
>   There are three basic actions that m2e
>   can be instructed to do with a plugin
>   execution -- **ignore**, **execute** and
>   delegate to a project **configurator**.

Answer (score 3):

If you search around, you'll find a lot of links showing you how to suppress that error.  However, I found a way to actually have the default Maven Project Builder execute these plugins within eclipse.  The key is to change the `<ignore>` you find in many suggestions to `<execute>`.  After adding this to my pom, I have automatic aggregation, compression, and deployment off of just a user saving a javascript resource:

```
<pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>
                                        net.alchim31.maven
                                    </groupId>
                                    <artifactId>
                                        yuicompressor-maven-plugin
                                    </artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>
                                        [1.1,)
                                    </versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>compress</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <execute></execute>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have to provide the id and phase?

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>yuicompressor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>compressyui</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>compress</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <jswarn>false</jswarn>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

At least i don't get that message with this configuration.

Comment: You don't need an ID if it's the only execution, and if you don't specify a phase it uses the default phase. Are you using the latest m2e downloaded from the Indigo site from within Eclipse, or are you using some older m2eclipse you downloaded from Sonatype a while ago? (I'd be willing to bet the latter.)

Comment: Yes, i was using an old version. Now i also get this error in the pom.xml. But nevertheless the plugin is called in my build. Is that also the case in your build? I assume this is a bug in the pom.xml editor of the new plugin.